# Modern OO practices in Java

Tags: java, oop

This is more of a conceptual question than technical pertaining to Java. I've noticed lately programmers tend to avoid creating classes to pass data around and simply move it using `JSONObject` if available or a basic `HashMap`. A lot of new interviewees choose to use what I call a JavaScript method of coding. So instead of creating class called `Address`, they would store it all in `JSONObject/HashMap` and pass it around as Object later casting to appropriate type. Also I notice a lot of

```
try { ... } 
finally { return str; }
```

structured methods.

Is this something normal and accepted these days? To me, it just goes against everything I was thought in school. I mean, no generalization, no encapsulation, etc... And when asked, they claim `JSONObject` is encapsulation. Well, not disagreeing, but just not something expected.

The task is always being done in the end, but the way its done is disturbing to me. This kind of practice produces a lot of loose structures with a lot of potential errors if programmers are not careful. Wasn't java generics created to avoid exactly that?

Feel free to move this question to other exchange, but I'd really like to hear some opinions from seasoned folks.

Comment: Don't close this. Its a legitimate question.

Comment: "I'd like to hear some opinions from seasoned folks." This isn't a 'Tell me your opinion' site.  We even have a close reason that states that.

Comment: OK. The opinion was to a question "Is this a normal practice these days" not to the OO concept. That's all I want to know. If other exchange is better suited for this question, please suggest as I cannot keep track of all of them to properly post it.

Comment: If you really want it re-opened, you need to do the following: Make the title more narrow. No one will ever search for 'modern OO practices in Java' and expect to come across anything less than a novel (which we don't do). Second,you're asking about a trend. Show us code; show us what you see people using; "Is this something normal and accepted?" Is not a question we can ever answer, you may want to edit that out.

Comment: Also your opinion on what it goes against can be edited out and changed to something that references literature on the subject (for instance, if it breaks one of the SOLID principles, tell us which one and how it breaks it) The fact that something is 'disturbing to you' does not make it a valid question. Explain how it produces a lot of loose structures with a lot of potential errors. Give us concrete examples and a concrete argument to back it up.  Show us how Java generics were created to avoid that and how they do so. This is what you need to do to have it be a viable question *anywhere*.

Comment: Thank you all, I will edit to make my question more solid.